# Angular2 npm packages - How would I know what to download?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, npm

I find it very hard to know what packages/libraries I should use when I want to create an empty(!) - *non angular-cli* -  app.

Starts by when I search `angular2` in npmjs I get unwanted results , And I need to  click :

[image]

In order to get to a [messy list](https://www.npmjs.com/~angularcore) where I don't know if one module can be used with another :

[image]

Also - Even if I use the `@angular/core` js , I don't know which files I should include in order to use other components.

Let's take for example  - I want to use `HTTP` - [The messy list doesn't contain any `http` in there](https://www.npmjs.com/~angularcore) And when I go to the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=http)  - I see it's from `@angular/http` and then I go again to npmjs and type `@angular/http` and then I use `unpkg.com` in order to get to the file system ( using unpkg.com's chrome extension)  just to download the js file :

[image]

This is *very* unfriendly. (*not to mention that changes in the packages are made quite often - but the internet never forgets*)

I don't want to use angular-cli and to be downloaded with things which I don't know what they do ( and if I need them).

And so I ask :

**Question**

jQuery has a [download builder page](https://jqueryui.com/download/) which allows you to choose what to download  - according to what you need !. How can I download (for angular2) only components ( and their dependencies components) that I need  ?

For example  - I was looking [at this basic angular 2 -  plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ss86otkTSD7KJFUTgEf6?p=preview)'s map section of `system.js`

```
  map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs@5.0.1',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript@5.2.7/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.0.10/lib/typescript.js',

    },
```

How did the plunker's author knew which packages ( *except for the `common/core/http/router` packages which seems legit to take*) - to download ?

Can someone please make some clarifications or am I doing it completely wrong ?

Comment: Why not just use an existing quick-start/seed project?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  As a senior developer -  I don't find it odd  wanting to understand  what am I downloading  - especially when starting ng2 from scratch. ANd I expect that things would be much easier to find - unless - again - i'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: Then why don't you start with just `@angular/core` and see what errors you get?

Comment: When you look at the initial startup files: main.ts, app.module.ts, app.component.ts, you'll find import statements like: `import { Component } from '@angular/core'`. That' gives you a clue as to which modules you want to load and why. As you load them, sometimes there are dependent modules that you need to also import (i.e. `@angular/common`)

Comment: it's always a good idea to start with the official documentation then work your way to narrowing down to the only packages you need. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Why would you need to download the files? Npm and webpack with its tree shaking already do all the things for you. Downloading the files, library constructors,  sounds like I'm back to the 2000x nightmare. It's not angular who is doing it unfriendly, problem is in the way you choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your pain , here is what I know after a year of working with Angular.

1- Angular2 is written in Javascript, so in theory you should be able to add a script to your index.html and kick off your app, BUT this is not preferred nor fully documented and supported and almost all the SO questions are written and answered in `typescript`.

So first , you need typescript installed :

```
 npm install typescript.
```

2- Angular have been putting a lot of effort to seperate the modules, but some of them still are intertwined but generally speaking, here are the main ones that you need to start.

```
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
```

You'd need those five to start a app.

You need core , because it's core .

You need `platform-browser-dynamic` to bootstrap your app module, otherwise you won't be able to run it.

And `platform-browser-dynamic` itself needs `platform-browser`.

You need rxjs because angular is heavily using it for almost every async function.

You need Zonejs because Angular is heavily using it for all the changeDetection ( why on earth didn't they include it in core then ?!)

That's it.

---

What would you do with your typescript code ? you'd need to run `tcs` to compile it and for that you need a `tsconfig.json` ( google it).

Now, if you need to run this code in an express server , you probably need a task to watch your code and compile it for ya, which these days webpack seems to be very promising and rollup.

So if you wanted , you'd need to install `webpack` which you can think of it as a sophisticated task runner who can bundle the generated+minifed code for ya.

And webpack also offers a local dev server ( no need to manually install express or ... ) which is called `webpack-dev-server` which you can install and that will take care of watching your code and running all the webpack job .

I'd suggest to have a look at AngularClass's Angular2 seed , try removing all the unnecessary stuff ( karma , protractor, all those jazz ) and then go from there.

Generally speaking, it's a bit difficult to do all of these and I'd suggest to use cli or AngularClass's seed.

By the way, none of those million modules inside cli or any of those seed will be bundled unless you import them, so doesn't matter how many things you `npm install` unless you import it in your project.